# Python and Matlab differences in linear algebra calculates

Tags: python, numpy, matlab, scipy, linear-algebra

I need to write a program for linear algebra calculates. I switched from Matlab to python and worked with numpy and scipy. There are some small differences in precision between Python and Matlab which cause different result in the end. For example for the matrix

```
A =[2       -25,
    -25     -622]
```

in Matlab `det(A) = 627.0` while in python it is `626.9999999999978`. When I check the variables, these tiny differences for all the variables will significantly change the results. what shall I do?

Comment: But `627.0==626.9999999999978`, the numbers **are** the same.  Perhaps you need to learn how to tell Matlab to show you more of the fractional part of the number?  Then, search for *is floating point math broken* on this site and the rest of the 'net and start to learn some more about the fun of floating-point computations.

Comment: oh well, you are in for a treat. Welcome to doing maths on a computer. It gets harder from here on. Good luck hehe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Floating points are finicky. When you run into precision problems
you can examine the numbers here:

[image: Floating point representation of 626.9999999999978]

In this case 626.9999999999978 is 627.
Admitted the number formatter could have done a better job.

For more advice on floating point numbers:
https://floating-point-gui.de/errors/comparison/

If you know that all you matrix entries are integers,
then consider using a representation of matrices
that doesn't use floating points.